# How can i send data from React Native Webview to my reactjs website?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i got stuck when trying to send back data from react native to my website.

here's my code

React Native

```
const onMessage = (e) => {
   setData(e?.nativeEvent?.data);
 }

<WebView
   ref={webviewRef}
   bounces={false}
   source={{ uri: 'http://192.168.148.130:3000' }}
   onMessage={onMessage}
/>
```

does anyone can help me to send back data to website?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native

Answer (score 0):

Create a function on react native end :

```
function sendDataToWebView() {
    webviewRef.current.postMessage('Data from React Native App');
  }
```

Create a function on website to listen to the input provided by react-native:

```
  window.addEventListener("message", message => 
          {
                alert(message.data) 
          });
```

Comment: But window.addEventListener("message") will listen to every event in the app. is there is any another way so that we can specify specific event type name for it

Comment: No, but you can inject custom method calls like this .... Good thing, it will clear after execution, so you attach many..... window.dataApi.getCustomers = async () => {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(
            JSON.stringify({type: 'InjectAction', key: ‘getCustomers’})
        );
       
        window.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
            resolve({data: messagePayload.data, error: messagePayload.error});
        },{capture: true, once: true});
    });
  
    return promise;
};

Comment: @venkateshParihar you can send along the source information:
```
    postMessage(JSON.stringify({from: 'app1', text: "hello"}))
    if(JSON.parse(message.data).from === 'app1') ...
```